# React with MobX: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): project.record.comments.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

My store has an item that the initial value is set to an empty array.

In the store constructor, I load the data from API.

When I try to iterate that array in React Component I sometimes (sometimes it works, sometimes not) get an exception:

`Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): project.record.comments.map is not a function`

*store file*

```js
class RecordStore {
  @observable comments = [];

  constructor() {
    this.loadComments();
  }

  loadComments = async () => {
    const api = new refineryApi();
    const comments = await api.getComments(
      this.documentCode,
      this.payload.project
    );
    this.comments = comments.data || [];
  };
```

*react component*

```js
const ListComments = () => {
  const project = useContext(projectStore);
  return (
    <div>
      {project.record.comments.map((item) => (
        <Comment data={item} key={item?.uid} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Note:** I actually have two stores: project (the main one) and record. In the **project** store, I have an observable **record** where I set the second store as a reference.  You can see it from this line above `project.record.comments`

The Exception I get at random as it seems that it depends on how fast the request to API is processed:
`Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): project.record.comments.map is not a function`

Comment: Well, it seems that sometimes you api response is not correct. Have you tried to log what you get after await when you get exception and compare it with what you expect?

Comment: Danila, you were right on spot. Indeed my API returned HTTP 200, but with an exception inside instead of expected data